# Any examples or tutorials for spray-caching

Tags: java, scala, spray

I have big problem - official docs are too small and not well informing and there no other materials for spray-caching library and google can`t help me. It can be SO question, github or blog entry.

**UPD** : is there any example for cache some table from db step by step? i need it for better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try reading these places [Tutorial for Spray Caching](http://www.superloopy.io/articles/2014/spray-example.html)

Check here for [GitHub Repository for Sample Codes](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-caching/src/main/scala/spray/caching/Cache.scala)

Comment: thanks, but is it all information and nothing other else?

Comment: is there any example for cache some table from db step by step? i need it for better understanding.